# Is there any difference between 制定, 制订 and 拟定?

Tags: meaning, difference

制订 work (map) out; formulate; draw up; evolve

制定 lay down; draw up; formulate; draft; establish; enact; work out

拟定 to draw up; to draft; to formulate

Would it be correct to say that 制定 is when you make a more complete plan of something, while 制订 and 拟定 is when you make more of a draft of something?

Comment: ＂汉语水平考试词典＂ **拟** ［义１］设计（计划）；打草稿（draw up):～订｜～稿｜秘书先～好草稿，再由厂长修改｜我们先草～一份计划，再来讨论。 **拟定** （动）［联合］［义１］起草并制定（计划）（draw up)～方案｜～一个切实可行的远景规划｜开学前，教学计划已经～好了。
  **制**  ［义２］规定；拟定（work out):这些规则是由总经理～定的｜种庄稼应该因地～宜。
 **制定**  （动）［联合］［义２］设想并确定（法律、计划、规则等）（lay down;draw up;formulate):这个社会～了一系列的章程｜暑假开始时～了一个切实可行的计划。 **制订**  （动）［联合］［义２］拟定（map out)我帮你～了一个学习计划｜～了＂汉语拼音方案＂。jukuu：  **拟定**   draw work draft design lay work out draw up １００samples， **制定**  make establish work enact set draw lay frame １００samples  **制订**  work draw prepare map evolve work out draw up map out １００samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

制订 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5836/

制定 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/5830/

拟定 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/20601/

> 制 *[1] [v] **establish**; institute; set up*
>
> 订 *[2] revise; **edit**; **amend**; make corrections*
>
> **制订** means 'to work out; **to formulate**'
>
> Example: 'The law makers **制订** a bill'
>
> The bill is **formulated** (also edit, amend before finalize )

~

> 制 *[1] [v] **establish**; institute; set up*
>
> 定 *[2] [v] **decide**; fix; set; settle*
>
> **制定** means 'to draw up; **to formulate**'
>
> Example: 'The law makers **制定** a bill'
>
> The bill is **formulated and set**'

~

> 拟  *[1] **intend**; **plan**; decide
>   [2] **draft**; **draw up**; design*
>
> 定 *[2] [v] **decide**; fix; set; settle*
>
> **拟定** means '**to draft**; plan'
>
> Example: 'The law makers **拟定** a bill'
>
> The bill is **drafted**, **planed**